# Syntax to conditional import CSV in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following import method needs to handle input variables set as nil

```
def self.import(file, unit_id, profit_center_column [...]
  CSV.foreach(file.path, :col_sep => "\t", headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
    begin
     Asset.create(
        unit_id: unit_id,
        profit_center_id: row[profit_center_column] unless profit_center_column.nil?,
        [...]
```

Where the controller launching this method defines

```
params[:profit_center_column] = @unit.profit_center_column
```

where `@unit.profit_center_column = nil`.

I am hitting an unexpected `syntax error, unexpected modifier_unless, expecting ')'` I have never had to use parenthesis before using `unless` and I woudl expect the use of the comma here to clearly seperate the statements. Where is the syntax getting messed up?

Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.3.4 are in use.

*Note, I've also attempted if statements, but that led to loading random xxx_column information.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a conditional to the Asset's constructor. If you need to take care of it I'd suggest first initializing `Asset` with ensured not nil values and afterwards using setters for the remaining attributes:

```
asset = Asset.new(
    unit_id: unit_id,
    ....

asset.profit_center_id = row[profit_center_column] unless profit_center_column.nil?
asset.save
```

Comment: Yes... `create` is `new` plus `save` ... was focussing on the tree, not the forest!

Comment: actually the conditional should be `asset.profit_center_id = [...]`